# How to create a Multi-tab webpage

Tags: dreamweaver, html

I'd like to create a webpage with menus at the top, using Dreamweaver. So far the help info I have found online talks about using the "Spry" option from the "Insert" menu within Dreamweaver. But the version of Dreamweaver I have (latest downloaded from Adobe) does not have "Spry" when I go to "Insert". I found "Tabs" under "jQuery UI" under "Insert", and that looks great but when I tested it with IE, there was a pop-up "Internet Explorer restricted this webpage from running scripts or ActiveX controls" and the page looks all garbled up, unless I click "Allow blocked content". I cannot assume that end users will have the right setting on their IE to make this work and it may just look like the webpage is not well built.
Any advice on how I should proceed?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

According to online help (https://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/using/spry-widgets-general-instructions.html), Spry widgets are replaced with jQuery widgets in Dreamweaver CC and later. While you can still modify existing spry widgets on your page, you cannot add new spry widgets.

Regarding the problem of the page looking garbled up if scripts are turned off in the browser, I guess the only way around it is to code in such a way that the page degrades gracefully in browsers that don't support JavaScript.

I found a workable solution here:
http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-tabs/